# if both values are equal to each other then do this c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First of all, here's my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Steamworks;

public class Achievements : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int currentScore=0;

    public static int score300 = 300;
    public static int score1000 = 1000;
    public static int score3600 = 3600;
    public static int score18000 = 18000;
    public static int score72000 = 72000;
    public static int score180000 = 180000;

    void Start() {

        if(SteamManager.Initialized) {

            string name = SteamFriends.GetPersonaName();
            Steamworks.SteamUserStats.SetAchievement("NEW_ACHIEVEMENT_1_0");
            Steamworks.SteamUserStats.StoreStats();

            Debug.Log(name);

        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        currentScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore");

        if (currentScore == score300 && SteamManager.Initialized){

            Steamworks.SteamUserStats.SetAchievement("NEW_ACHIEVEMENT_5_0");
            Steamworks.SteamUserStats.StoreStats();

        }

        if (currentScore == score1000 && SteamManager.Initialized) {

            Steamworks.SteamUserStats.SetAchievement("NEW_ACHIEVEMENT_6_0");
            Steamworks.SteamUserStats.StoreStats();

        }
        if (currentScore == score3600 && SteamManager.Initialized) {

            Steamworks.SteamUserStats.SetAchievement("NEW_ACHIEVEMENT_7_0");
            Steamworks.SteamUserStats.StoreStats();

        }
        if (currentScore == score18000 && SteamManager.Initialized) {

            Steamworks.SteamUserStats.SetAchievement("NEW_ACHIEVEMENT_8_0");
            Steamworks.SteamUserStats.StoreStats();

        }

    }
}
```

As you can see, I have public integers that hold variety of numbers. I am also using current steamworks.net, and I'm trying to see if I can match both "highscore" (which is already set up and working properly) with scoreXXX. If that happens, I want script to drop an achievement.

Am I executing if(x=x) function wrong? Can someone please help?

Comment: The comparison looks fine. Are you sure the score will go up in increments and be exactly equal at the time of `Update`? You may want to use `>=`. I would add some logging of the value of `currentScore` after it's loaded to debug, and possibly inside each `if` block to verify whether the blocks are entered.

Comment: @GiladGreen I presume based on "I want script to drop an achievement" that the script in fact did not "drop an achievement".

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you arent checking if the score is *greater* than the score benchmarks, only that its *equal*.

You could simplify your code a bit by putting these values into a `Dictionary<int, string>`:

```
private static Dictionary<int, string> highScoreDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 300, "NEW_ACHIEVEMENT_5_0" },
    { 1000, "NEW_ACHIEVEMENT_6_0" },
    { 3600, "NEW_ACHIEVEMENT_7_0" },
    { 18000, "NEW_ACHIEVEMENT_8_0" },
    { 72000, "NEW_ACHIEVEMENT_9_0" },
    { 180000, "NEW_ACHIEVEMENT_10_0" }      
};

void Update()
{
    currentScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore");

    if(SteamManager.Initialized)
    {
        //Order by high score, descending
        foreach(var score in highScoreDictionary.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key))
        {
            //If the score is greater than or equal to the benchmark
            //Then add the achievement 
            if(currentScore >= score.Key)
            {
                Steamworks.SteamUserStats.SetAchievement(score.Value);
                Steamworks.SteamUserStats.StoreStats();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q0Du7J).  Its obviously modified a bit since I dont have access to Unity libraries there, but you can see the logic in action.

Comment: Hey @maccettura! Appreciate your help first of all. I've put it in my script, well, created a new one just in case with your code, updated a few things to make sure all variables worked, ran the game and achievement did not drop. For example, my current highScore is 300 but achievement for 300 didn't drop. Nothing.

And yes, it is defined on steamworks itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well I just tried my fiddle with the score of 300 exactly and it worked as intended.  I imagine your issue is with Steamworks, not with the logic.

Comment: I don't know much about Unity3D, but I imagine there has to be a way to debug.  Put a breakpoint on the line that calls `Steamworks.SteamUserStats.SetAchievement(score.Value);` and see if it ever gets hit.  If it does and an acheivement never fires, that means you need to figure out why _SteamWorks specifically_ is not working.

Comment: Fair enough. But steamwork does work. If I just put achievement drop on the start, it will drop no problem.

Comment: Maybe the issue is with this? Steamworks.SteamUserStats.SetAchievement(score.Value);

Comment: The only way to tell is to use the debugger